# Creating a directory on a server that IIS will be able to access files from but the public can't

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I am trying to create a directory on a production server that several IIS websites will be able to access and read files from. I keep getting the following error:

> Severe Error  A severe error has occurred. Error message: Access to
>   the path 'C:\Secrets\config.json' is denied.

Can someone give me a technique that will work? I am setting the path to the file in the Web.Config as an appsetting.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, servers in the production environment have their C: drive protected with administrator level. This is the best practice since this is usually the place where the OS files reside.

In my opinion, just move your files away from drive C:, to another drive with lower security settings. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the sites are on the same server as the folder, you just need to give the user running the application pool (for example Network Service) rights to that folder. As a bad practice, but a good test, you can try adding rights to Everyone. This is just to test that sites can reach the folder.